# How can I have two of these on one page with different variables? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to have 2 of these one page but each with different percentages. When I try re-writing the JS or even use different class/ID names it still always pulls from the first SPAN.

http://jsfiddle.net/K62Ra/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="bw"></div>
<div class="show"></div>
<div id="bar" data-total="100">
    <div class="text">Currently at <br/><span>70</span><br><i>Click To Give</div>
</div>
```

JS and CSS in the Fiddle.

Much Thanks.

Comment: Going to have to be more specific. What you tried is too vague.

Comment: So what is your issue? If using more than one element, you have to target specific element

Comment: Obviously because you use the stored one from the first `span` when doing `percent = $('#bar div span').html()`

Comment: You cannot duplicate id's within an HTML document or you'll get funny results. And by funny I mean puzzling. And post some of your code here so that it will be preserved for future generations.

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't specific enough. I need 2 of these side by side but with different percentage values. I essentially just copied the HTML but changed everything to "container2" wrote the same JS over but using "container2" etc.. Got everything to work but it keeps whatever is in the first <span> for both images. I'm not that great with JS so it's possible I am rewriting the code wrong.

Comment: I don't quite have everything correct here, but this may give you a start - http://jsfiddle.net/K62Ra/2/

Comment: You should create a fiddle of what didn't work for you. I have a feeling you just missed duplicating a variable and if you post the code you have that doesn't work we can point that out.

Answer (score 1):

This one will work smoothly:

http://jsfiddle.net/K62Ra/7/

```
$('.bar').each(function() {
    var percentStart = 0;
    var total = $(this).data('total');
    var percent = parseInt($(this).find('span').html());

    $(this).find('> div').addClass("load");

    var that = this;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        $(that).siblings('.show').css('height', percentStart/total*100+'%');
        $(that).css('height', percentStart/total*100+'%');
        $(that).find('span').html('%'+percentStart);
        if(percentStart<percent) { percentStart=percentStart+1; return; }
        clearInterval(timer);
    }, 35);
});
```

The interval has to be terminated as well, or it will run infinitely (though not doing anything).

Comment: @user3324440 Please check updated code. I had an error displaying percentage and also added `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your `id="bar"` into a class. Then I'm running a `each loop` for the `.bar` classes. here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K62Ra/3/

here is the code:

```
$('.bar').each(function (index, element) {
  percent = $(this).find('span').html();

  total = $(this).attr('data-total');
  percentStart = 0;

  setInterval(function () {
    $('.show').css('height', percentStart / total * 100 + '%');
    $(this).css('height', percentStart / total * 100 + '%');
    $(this).find('span').html('%' + percentStart);
    if (percentStart < percent) {
        percentStart = percentStart + 1;
    }
  }, 35);


});
$(".bar div").addClass("load");
```

Comment: Please add your code here so that future generations may see it.

Answer (score 0):

Like some of the comments have stated, having duplicate ids is bad design and can cause some weird errors.

You can find a solution to your problem by changing a number of things. One, instead of
referring to divs in you selectors by id'#', you can infer them by class '.' like

```
$('.bar')
```

The next step would be to ensure exclusivity for each div with class 'container' by using a closure

```
$('.container').each(function(){
   var x
   var y
   .
   .
});
```

And finally, avoid 'selecting' elements in the selector directly, but use $(this) and .find() to ensure you are within the current div with class 'container'.

http://jsfiddle.net/K62Ra/5/

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    var percent = $(this).find('div.bar div span').html();
    var total = $(this).find('div.bar').attr('data-total');
    var percentStart = 0;

    var that = $(this);

    setInterval(function() {
      that.find('.show').css('height',percentStart/total*100+'%');
      that.find('div.bar').css('height',percentStart/total*100+'%');
      that.find('div.bar div span').html('%'+percentStart);
      if(percentStart<percent) {percentStart=percentStart+1;}
    },35);

    $(this).find("div.bar div").addClass("load");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already several good answers here. I would recommend validating your html. Also some of your css was causing weirdness when there was scrolling involved (fixed background images weren't scrolling.)

I took a slightly different approach than everyone else. Instead of using a setInterval I went with $.animate and a step function. Like others, I chose a class to target each of the items: 'fill-me-up'.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LFbKs/6/

***NOTE**: Check the fiddle since I modified the HTML (very slightly) and the css to a larger degree.*

```
// for each item we need to "fill up"
$('.fill-me-up').each(function(){

    // cache DOM references
    var this$ = $(this)
      , bar$ = this$.find('.bar')
      , show$ = this$.find('.show')
      , span$ = bar$.find('div span')

      // the target percentage height for this item
      , p = span$.text()

      // combine '.bar' and '.show' so we can apply the animation to both
      , toAnimate = $().add(bar$).add(show$);

    // add class causing fade-in
    bar$.find('div').addClass('is-visible');

    // animate height to target height over 2 seconds and 
    // at each step, update the span with a truncated value
    toAnimate.animate(
        { height: p+'%' },
        { 
            duration: 2000,
            step: function( currentStep ) {
                span$.html('%'+currentStep.toFixed(0));
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Cheers

Comment: It seemed unnecessary to have the data-total="100" attribute so I omitted it assuming that we're always scaling to a percentage out of 100. If you need that functionality I'd be happy to edit my answer taking that into account.

Comment: Additionally, you could change the duration to some constant multiplied by the percentage (e.g. p*30) if you want the animations to progress at the same rate instead of all completing at the same time.